# Intent is not working on click event

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

Hy experts.
i am new to android, i am trying to generate an intent to go on next activity, i am using listview, when i click on list item, it should go to that class which item item is clicked.
here is my code.

`package com.example.data_server_assi;`

`import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;`

public class Menu extends ListActivity{

```
String[] menu = {"AddInfo","DataBaseInfo"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu));
}
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    try {

        Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "Test" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Class menuItem = Class.forName("com.example.data_server_assi."+menu[position]);

        Intent menuIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,menuItem);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: Toast is working but below two lines of Toast is not working.

Comment: you are missing out on startActivity(intent) line.

Answer (score 1):

Put below code, You have missed one line of code:

```
Intent menuIntent = new Intent(Menu.this,menuItem);
 startActivity(menuIntent);
```

OR

```
startActivity(new Intent(menu.this,menuItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed starting your activity by-

```
startActivity(YOUR_INTENT_NAME);
```